# Clone repository without rewriting files

Tags: git, git-clone

I have an own config in this directory.

```
my-app/
├─ .git/
├─ src/
│  ├─ config.json
```

Then I'd like to clone another foreign repository named `src`, which contains `config.json` as well, but I don't want to delete my own config.

How can I clone `src.git` to the same `src` folder, but without rewriting my `config.json`?

Comment: Don't. What you do is first clone the repository to a new, empty, folder. Then afterwards you move the .git folder into your existing working folder, and also copy/move any files you *do* want to update from the fresh cloned working folder. This way you get what you want, a clone, and a git repository, set up in your existing working folder, with complete control over what happens to your existing files. I would make a complete backup of your existing working folder first, just to be sure you don't mess anything up.

Comment: Do you actgually need both at the same time?

Comment: @Ivan No, I need just my own `config.json`.